# Export-Csv MIM FIM PowerShell Issue

Tags: powershell

I was asked to retrieve a *.csv* list with all users that registered to the *FIM portal*. I did some searching until I stumbled accross this script:

```
set-variable -name URI -value "http://localhost:5725/resourcemanagementservice' " -option constant 
set-variable -name CSV -value "RegistredResetPassUsers.csv" -option constant

clear 

If(@(Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "FIMAutomation"} ).count -eq 0) {Add-PSSnapin FIMAutomation} 

$WFDFilter = "/WorkflowDefinition[DisplayName='Password Reset AuthN Workflow']" 
$curObjectWFD = export-fimconfig -uri $URI –onlyBaseResources -customconfig ($WFDFilter) -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$WFDObjectID = (($curObjectWFD.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object {$_.AttributeName -eq "ObjectID"}).value).split(":")[2]
$Filter = "/Person[AuthNWFRegistered = '$WFDObjectID']"
$curObject = export-fimconfig -uri $URI –onlyBaseResources -customconfig ($Filter) -ErrorVariable Err -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 

[array]$users = $null 
foreach($Object in $curObject) 
{
     $ResetPass = New-Object PSObject
     $UserDisplayName = (($Object.ResourceManagementObject.ResourceManagementAttributes | Where-Object {$_.AttributeName -eq "DisplayName"}).Value)
     $ResetPass | Add-Member NoteProperty "DisplayName" $UserDisplayName
     $Users += $ResetPass
}

$users | export-csv -path $CSV
```

The script works without errors except that the actual list that it exports only *contains my display name*. I've been trying to figure out why its not exporting the complete list of all users and only shows my name, but I haven't been able to figure it out so I was wondering if any one could help me shed some light into this issue.

Thanks again for any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 0):

No experience with this snapin/product, but seeing as the code fundamentally works (it returns your object) this could be a permissions issue. You may not be able to read the other user objects, so they're not being exposed to you.

If you can view them in a UI console of some kind, then check for separate permissions related to API actions, and ensure you have access that way.
Another course of action may be to run the code line by line and see what results you receive from each line, to make sure you get what you're expecting.

Comment: Getting this error on the last line. Which I believe refers to the fact that I'm not receiving any info.

`Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At line:23 char:10
+ $users | export-csv -path $CSV -Encoding Default
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
`

Comment: Perhaps you're not storing the user objects in the array appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
[array]$users = $null
```

With:

```
$users = @()
```

Comment: After doing this I no longer received the error on line 23 but the exported .csv file is empty... I don't understand X_X.

Comment: Run each line 1 by 1 before storing the results in the array to confirm your code works before that part.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to permission setup.

By default you have a permissions to see your own attributes.

There is likely some Management Policy Rule setup so user accounts in a specific Set can read AuthNWFRegistered attribute of other users to support for troubleshooting and customer support.

You will need to use one of the options:

- Add the account used for this script into the Set that delegates out this Read permission already

or

- Create a separate MPR for this particular reporting (this is what I would recommend) that Grants permissions for a specific user account to read AuthNWFRegistered attribute.

Also make sure there is really only one Workflow that is associated with user registration. If there are multiple, you'd want to target Set with all register Workflows in your XPath filter instead of particular Workflow name.

On a separate note - while FIMAutomation is sometimes necessary snapin to use with standard tooling, for your custom work I strongly suggest to use Lithnet's **LithnetRMA** PowerShell module (https://github.com/lithnet/resourcemanagement-powershell).

You will be much more productive with it and most of the operations will be without boilerplate code FIMAutomation needs. This will be your code using LithnetRMA.

```
Set-ResourceManagementClient -BaseAddress 'http://localhost:5725/resourcemanagementservice'
$scope = Search-Resources -XPath "/Person[AuthNWFRegistered = /WorkflowDefinition[DisplayName='Password Reset AuthN Workflow']]" -ExpectedObjectType Person
$scope | select DisplayName | Export-Csv 'RegistredResetPassUsers.csv' -Encoding Unicode
```